# Flutter - How to update single item in pagination list

Tags: flutter

https://github.com/vedartm/pagination_view

I use the above library for pagination in a flutter.

I want to update single item on tap on heart sign.(without refreshing all items.)

I used paginatio_view library it's work perfect. but i want change pericualr item on tap on heart icon without refresh all list.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVof0.png

```
Expanded(
    flex: 1,
    child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: PaginationView < ProductList > (
                key: key,
                paginationViewType: PaginationViewType.gridView,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                pageFetch: (page) => pageFetch(page),
                pullToRefresh: true,
                itemBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, ProductList user, int index) {
                    return GridTile(
                        child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                                children: [
                                    Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                        child: Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                child: InkWell(
                                                    onTap: () => {
                                                        controller.addToWishList({
                                                                "ProductId": user.productId
                                                            }),
                                                            key
                                                    },
                                                    child: Image.asset(
                                                        height: 20,
                                                        width: 20,
                                                        user.flag ?
                                                        "assets/images/ic_like_heart.png" :
                                                        "assets/images/ic_unlike_heart.png")),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                        flex: 1,
                                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                            imageUrl: user.image,
                                            imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) =>
                                            Container(
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                                        image: imageProvider,
                                                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                                    ),
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                            progressIndicatorBuilder:
                                            (context, url, progress) => Center(
                                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                                    value: progress.progress,
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                            errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                            const Icon(Icons.warning_amber_rounded),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                            child: Text(user.productName),
                                    )
                                ],
                            ),
                        ),
                    );
                },
                onError: (dynamic error) =>
                const Center(
                        child: Text(
                            'Some error occurred',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                    ),
                    onEmpty: const Center(
                            child: Text(
                                'Sorry! This is empty',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                        ),
                        bottomLoader: const Center( // optional
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ),
                            initialLoader: const Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Center(
                                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
                                ),
                            ),
            ),
    ),
)
```

Here is the method to get list.

```
Future < List < ProductList >> pageFetch(int offset) async {
    page = (offset / 10).round() + 1;
    _logger.d("Offset number::$offset Page number::$page");

    var data = {
        'Category': '',
        'Search': _search,
        'PageNumber': page,
        'PageCount': 10
    };
    return await controller.getProductsList(data, page);
}
```

Comment: Do we have found out any solution for this yet? We would be happy if we have one applied and working perfectly.